# Setting automationIDs across an existing application

Tags: wpf, xaml, ui-automation, winappdriver

If I have an existing WPF application, and I want to assign automationIDs to the entire application where they aren't set, what's a good way to do that (for controls that aren't dynamically added)? Some sort of script that goes through all the xaml files and adds automationIDs?

My goal is to write ui tests using winappdriver.

I've googled this, but haven't found anything that seems to do what I want. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the results. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43144581/is-there-any-way-by-which-automation-id-can-be-generated-automatically-for-wpf-c) seems to ask the same question, but I fail to see how the answer provided is an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, when a control name property has a value, this corresponds with the AutomationID you will find with a UI inspector tool like Inspect.exe. Take a look at the remarks section about automationID [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.name?view=netframework-4.7.2). So the application should already have most of its automationIDs.

The only time I did not have a automationID for a control was when the control was created in code. A script to adjust XAML won't help you here, because there won't be XAML for those controls. Even if you used a script, you won't be sure all automationIDs will be available.

When using 3rd party controls, the availability of a AutomationId depend on the 3rd party supporting it or not. If they do not support AutomationId, you could wrap that control in a custom control and expose a AutomationID that way.
Here are some resources that might be useful:

[wrapped control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820378/wrapped-wpf-control)

[UI automation of a WPF Custom Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/ui-automation-of-a-wpf-custom-control)

When working with a existing application, I usually just fill in the name property for a control as I go, so the amount of change to the application stays at a minimum.

Comment: The reason I asked the question to begin with is because I had used Inspect.exe and not found automationIDs for a lot of elements in the application I'm working with. It is using a third party UI library built on WPF, so perhaps that's blocking the behavior from the link you posted (that the name of the control corresponds to the automationID). I will look into that.

I also edited my original post to indicate it was not for dynamically created controls, as I had been thinking that, but not stated it.

Comment: Ah yes, I totally forgot about that. I updated my answer. Will expand my answer more when I get the time.